# Date Picker appears oversized bug

Tags: excel, user-interface, datepicker, vba

I am using a date picker in excel, that looks like this:

[image: normal state]

However whenever other users open the same excel file, and click on the drop down arrow, from the date picker, the calendar view looks buggy. More specifically it takes over the whole top of the screen, like in the picture below.
[image: buggy state]

Where is this coming from, and how can I fix it? It's been driving me nuts?

Comment: It looks like the DatePicker ActiveX has several bugs (that you cannot fix, and Microsoft seems not interested in fixing them), and you might want to avoid it at all. You might find several alternatives to that DatePicker ActiveX in the web. But just in case is there any VBA code involved with the DatePicker? If yes please show that code by [edit]ing your original question.

Comment: What kind of `DatePicker` is this? From external library, some addin, custom Form? Do the other users have teh external library installed as well?

Comment: @Vityata, I am using "Microsoft Date and Time Pucker Control 6.0"

Comment: @Pᴇʜ does this apply for "Microsoft  Date and Time Picker Control 6.0" as well?

Comment: @dre_84w934 - Is your version of Excel the same as the one of your colleagues? E.g., do you both have 32 bits? With Excel 2013/2016? Have you located this control through browse? If you go to the PC of one of your colleagues, open an empty Excel, are you able to locate it?

Comment: @Vityata , just checked and yes, we are all using the 32 bits ex 2010

Comment: @dre_84w934 - and if you go to your colleagues, and try from empty Excel file, can you insert the `time picker control 6.0` as well?

Comment: @Vityata yes, we can all insert time picker 6.0

Comment: @dre_84w934 Yes, it's not the first time I hear about displaying issues with the Microsoft DatePicker. Is there any VBA code involved with the Datepicker?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ no, no other code involved. I guess I'll just use omething else then. Maybe I'll just go with the plain calendar picker

Comment: @dre_84w934 then I guess this is just another of the numerous displaying bugs this ActiveX has. You are not the first one having displaying issues with DatePicker, but these are bugs, so I think you won't be able to fix them. But if you google you will find several alternatives to the DatePicker that might fit your needs.